# Can i modify setter getter in xx_Roo_JavaBean.aj through xx.java in spring-roo?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-roo

below is a sample class:

**AAAA.java**

```
  1 package tp.domain;
  2 
  3 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
  4 import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
  5 import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord.RooJpaActiveRecord;
  6 import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;
  7 
  8 @RooJavaBean
  9 @RooToString
 10 @RooJpaActiveRecord
 11 public class AAAA {
 12                             
 13     @Value("true")         
 14     private Boolean a;
 15 }
```

**AAAA_Roo_JavaBean.aj**

```
  4 package top.tap.domain;
  5 
  6 import top.tap.domain.AAAA;
  7 
  8 privileged aspect AAAA_Roo_JavaBean {
  9 
 10     public Boolean AAAA.getA() {
 11         return this.a;
 12     }
 13 
 14     public void AAAA.setA(Boolean a) {
 15         this.a = a;
 16     }
 17 
 18 }
```

I like to modify getter setter via entity class (AAAA.java). Can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Run the Roo Shell, either through Eclipse/STS if you are using it, or command line if not.  Add the getters/setters you want to over-write, and the Roo Shell will see this and remove the conflicting getters/setters from the .aj file.

Comment: I should also not, for future reference, you can also "push" the aspects into your code via STS.  I believe there are examples on how to do this on the Roo site.  Basically, find the method in the AJ file, right click, and choose "Push-In".  The method is then pushed back into your class.  Very helpful when you need to take what Roo did and augment it.